# Obcure rendering error in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongrel

I'm working on a little CMS that has been custom written in Ruby, the website is running using Mongrel.
Unfortunately I am not at all familiar with Ruby. A part of the website has recently stopped working (not in connection with any updates or so, so I am unsure what was the cause)

Checking the "production.log" in the rails logs shows the following:

> ActionView::TemplateError (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass)
>   on line #25 of app/views/static/frontpage.rhtml: 22:     <%
>   Tabloid.find(:all, :limit => 4, :order =>'date DESC').each do
>   |tabloid|%>    23:     24:    <%= link_to tabloid.title, :controller =>
>   'tabloid', :action => 'show', :id => tabloid.id %> 25:
>
> <%=
>   tabloid.date.strftime("%d of %B, %Y") %> By: <%= Profile.find(:first,
>   :conditions => [ "user_id = ?", tabloid.user_id]).name %> <%=
>   Profile.find(:first, :conditions => [ "user_id = ?",
>   tabloid.user_id]).surname %>
>
> 26:
>
> <%=
>   RedCloth.new(truncate(tabloid.texto, 250)).to_html %>
>
> 27:     <% if
>   tabloid.texto.size > 250 %> 28:
>
> <%= link_to "Read more >",
>   :controller => 'tabloid', :action => 'show', :id => tabloid.id %>
>
> ```
> app/views/static/frontpage.rhtml:25
> app/views/static/frontpage.rhtml:22:in `each'
> app/views/static/frontpage.rhtml:22
> /usr/local/rubygems/gems/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:39:in
> ```
>
> `send'
>       /usr/local/rubygems/gems/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:39:in`
>   render'
>       /usr/local/rubygems/gems/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_view/template.rb:73:in
>   `render_template'
>       /usr/local/rubygems/gems/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_view/base.rb:256:in`
>   render'
>       /usr/local/rubygems/gems/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_view/base.rb:367:in
>   `_render_with_layout'
>       /usr/local/rubygems/gems/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_view/base.rb:254:in`
>   render'
>       /usr/local/rubygems/gems/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1174:in
>   `render_for_file'
>       /usr/local/rubygems/gems/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:896:in`
>   render_without_benchmark'
>       /usr/local/rubygems/gems/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:51:in
>   `render'
>       /usr/local/rubygems/gems/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:8:in`
>   realtime'
>       /usr/local/rubygems/gems/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:51:in
>   `render'
>       /usr/local/rubygems/gems/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:868:in`
>   render_without_benchmark'
>       /usr/local/rubygems/gems/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:51:in
>   `render'
>       /usr/local/rubygems/gems/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:8:in`
>   realtime'
>       /usr/local/rubygems/gems/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:51:in
>   `render'
>       /usr/local/rubygems/gems/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:122:in`
>   dispatch'
>       /usr/local/rubygems/gems/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:132:in
>   `dispatch_cgi'
>       /usr/local/rubygems/gems/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:39:in`
>   dispatch'
>       /usr/local/rubygems/gems/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/rails.rb:76:in
>   `process'
>       /usr/local/rubygems/gems/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/rails.rb:74:in`
>   synchronize'
>       /usr/local/rubygems/gems/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/rails.rb:74:in
>   `process'
>       /usr/local/rubygems/gems/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:159:in`process_client'
>       /usr/local/rubygems/gems/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:158:in `each'
>       /usr/local/rubygems/gems/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:158:in`process_client'
>       /usr/local/rubygems/gems/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run'
>       /usr/local/rubygems/gems/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in`initialize'
>       /usr/local/rubygems/gems/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `new'
>       /usr/local/rubygems/gems/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:282:in`
>   run'
>       /usr/local/rubygems/gems/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:281:in
>   `each'
>       /usr/local/rubygems/gems/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:281:in`
>   run'

etc.
The Mongrel logs actually haven't updated in a while. Any pointers as to what the problem is or where I should continue digging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Profile.find(:first, :conditions => [ "user_id = ?", tabloid.user_id])` query returns `nil` so he cant execute `name` on it

Comment: Thanks, there was indeed something wrong with those IDs, this brought me on track.